# Make \refstepcounter (\@currentlabel) visible outside its group

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, counters

I defined my own list environment. See the following MWE: (The actual definition is much more complicated in case why you ask why I am not using the standard lists)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{mylist}
\renewcommand*{\themylist}{\Alph{mylist}}
\newcommand*{\labelmylist}{\themylist}

\newcommand*{\makemylabel}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{mylist}%
\@mklab{\labelmylist}%
}

\newenvironment{mylist}{
  \list{\@empty}{
    \let\makelabel\makemylabel
    \setcounter{mylist}{0}
  }
}{
  \endlist
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

\begin{mylist}
  \item\label{foo} List entry 1
\end{mylist}

The reference are wrong: \ref{foo}.

\end{document}
```

The error is that `\ļabel{foo}` creates a reference to the subsection counter and thus `\ref{foo}` prints the wrong label.

I understand that `\refstepcounter` redefines `\@currentlabel` and `\label` ships `\@currentlabel` out to the aux file.

But `\refstepcounter` uses `\edef` (and not `\xdef`) and thus `\@currentlabel` is reset to its old definition after the `\makemylabel` commands ends. Thus `\label{foo}` uses the counter of `\section`.

How do I get `\label{foo}` to use the correct counter?

**Update due to comments**

The not so minimimal MWE due to questions from @david-carlisle and @alan-munn

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{mylist}
\renewcommand*{\themylist}{FA-\Alph{mylist}}
\newcommand*{\labelmylist}{\themylist}

\newcommand*{\makemylabel}[1]{%
\if#1\@empty\else\setcounter{mylist}{#1}\addtocounter{mylist}{-1}\fi%
\refstepcounter{mylist}%
\@mklab{\labelmylist}%
}

\newenvironment{mylist}{
  \list{\@empty}{
    \let\makelabel\makemylabel
    \setcounter{mylist}{0}
  }
}{
  \endlist
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

\begin{mylist}
  \item\label{foo} List entry A
  \item[5] List entry E
  \item\label{bar} List entry F
\end{mylist}

The reference are wrong: \ref{foo} and \ref{bar}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: the intended use is to use `\usecounter{mylist}` in your `\list` setup then setting to 0 and a `\refstepcounter` will be automatic at each \item

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. You cannot see that because of the MWE. In my case `\item[n]` does not use n as the label, but sets `\setcounter{mylist}{n}` and then use `\themylist` to produce the actual label. I did not want to redefine all the logic of `\item`  from "The L A TEX 2ε Sources
" so I tried to put that logic into `\makemylabel`. However all that is not shown in the MWE.

Comment: Then you need to explain exactly what you are trying to achieve since there may be a better way.

Comment: unrelated but `\if#1` is wrong, it will be true if the first two letters of `#1` are the same. try `\item[111] List entry E`

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be better to structure the code to use the first argument of `\list` that is there specifically to control the counter used for referencing, however starting from where you are, you can lift the definition of `\@currentlabel` out of the group using `\aftergroup`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{mylist}
\renewcommand*{\themylist}{FA-\Alph{mylist}}
\newcommand*{\labelmylist}{\themylist}

\newcommand*{\makemylabel}[1]{%
\if#1\@empty% you probably want \ifx\relax#1\relax
  \else\setcounter{mylist}{#1}\addtocounter{mylist}{-1}\fi%
\refstepcounter{mylist}%
\protected@xdef\zzz{\def\noexpand\@currentlabel{\@currentlabel}}%
\aftergroup\zzz
\@mklab{\labelmylist}%
}

\newenvironment{mylist}{%%%%% 
  \list{}{%%%%%
    \let\makelabel\makemylabel
    \setcounter{mylist}{0}%%%%%
  }
}{%%%%%%%%%%
  \endlist
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

\begin{mylist}
  \item\label{foo} List entry A
  \item[5] List entry E
  \item\label{bar} List entry F
\end{mylist}

The reference are wrong: \ref{foo} and \ref{bar}.

\end{document}
```